# Change global string pointer variable from inside a function?

Tags: string, pointers, arduino, esp8266, arduino-c++

Firstly i would like to apologize beforehand about this question. I imagine that it must be really straight forward, but i'm a beginner and had nowere to go.

I'm declaring the following pointers, outside all my functions (Global Variable):

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

String* IP;
String* MAC;
```

Then, from inside a function i'm trying to change it's values:

```
void networkInfo() {
    String* IP = WiFi.localIP().toString();
    String* MAC = WiFi.macAddress();
}
```

When i try to compile and execute, it gives me the following error:

```
error: cannot convert 'String' to 'String*' in initialization
String* IP = WiFi.localIP().toString();
                                                           ^

error: cannot convert 'String' to 'String*' in initialization
String* MAC = WiFi.macAddress();

                                                     ^
```

Please, what am i doing wrong?
Thanks...

PS: I would like to state that before asking this question i REALLY did search on StackOverflow, tried many different approachs but none helped for me. (Most were incomplete or just really specific to the OPs question)

If this is a duplicate, i'm sorry. I didnt find the solution for this.

**Edit 1:**

Changed pointers to normal variables:

```
// Global Variables
String IP; 
String MAC;
```

Inside the function, changed ways that the variable is assigned:

```
void networkInfo() {
  IP = new String;
  MAC = new String;
  *IP = WiFi.localIP().toString();
  *MAC = WiFi.macAddress();
}
```

But right here on networkInfo function it returned me a error.
Error on equals sign:

```
****no viable overloaded '='****
```

**Edit 2:**

Further tests below.

1. Changing variable names to address best practices, with g_Variable

> ```
> // Global Variables
> String *g_IP;
> String *g_MAC;
> ```

2. Assigning variable as objet then giving a string to it.

> ```
> void networkInfo() {
>   g_IP = new String;
>   g_MAC = new String;
>   *g_IP = WiFi.localIP().toString();
> }
>
> void sendInfo() { cout << "Test: " << g_IP; }
> ```

When calling sendInfo() function, the output was exactly:

```
Test: 0x22beeb0
```

I expected the IP Address.

**Edit 3 (Solution):**
For some weird reason i was able to solve this using g_IP = new String;
and then assigning as pointer. Weird, didnt understand why.

```
// Global Variables
String *g_IP; 
String *g_MAC;


// Prototypes - Functions you will use.
void networkInfo();
void sendInfo();
void initSerial();

void setup() 
{
  // Initialize Functions
  initSerial();
  networkInfo();
  sendInfo();

}

void loop() 
{   
  // Loop Functions
  sendInfo();
}

void initSerial() 
{
    Serial.begin(115200); // Baudrate NodeMCU
}

void networkInfo() {
  // Obs: Without new String a Error happens, below.
  // ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(1,6)
  // wdt reset

  // Why? IDK

  g_IP = new String; // No idea why this works.
  g_MAC = new String; 

// Removing this two lines and above gives wdt reset error

  *g_IP = WiFi.localIP().toString();
  *g_MAC = WiFi.macAddress();
}

void sendInfo() {
    delay(500);
    Serial.println(*g_IP);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in `void networkInfo()` you are declaring local variables that are hiding the global ones.

```
String* IP = (value)
```

Should just be

```
IP = (value)
```

in the function if you want IP to be the global version.  Some people will use a naming scheme like `g_IP` to make it clear that it is a global variable not a local.

Second, a pointer must be assigned the address of (something) not the (something) itself.

```
IP = new String
```

Will allocate a persistent string object on the heap and set IP to the address of it (a pointer to it).

Now that IP points to a String, *IP is the string and this will work

```
*IP = WiFi.localIP().toString();
```

As @CherryDT notes, you probably only want to allocate storage for the global variables once, in some initialization function.  If you keep allocating new objects every time this function is called you will leak memory.

Comment: Worth pointing out that the `IP = new String` part should be done upon initialization once and not directly before the assignment of the new IP value, because otherwise you will be leaking a string every time that part of the code runs and quickly crash or hang your Arduino.

Comment: @CherryDT - right, I thought of mentioning that but wanted to keep my answer as simple as possible.  It's an easy mistake to make so 'll add it to the end.

Comment: Hey. On step 1 i got a error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations ._.

Comment: I will edit the question with the output of your suggestions.

Comment: (1) was about you re-declaring the variables in `void networkInfo()`.  That creates a second variable that shares the same name.

Comment: Oh, i got it now. I see, so if i specifiy a pointer inside a function it will just be a new pointer and the one i did outside of the function will not be seen. Ok, i will test this and return here with the results.

Comment: Now the output was: Test: 0x22beeb0 

Comment: Check the expected value of `WiFi.localIP()` it might just be a 4-byte value that you need to split into the a.b.c.d yourself.

Comment: No, it was priting the memory address. I addded * at the beginning of the variable and the MAC was printed correctly.

Answer (score -2):

You're trying to put a String value into a String pointer type.

```
String* IP = WiFi.localIP().toString();
    //  ^ This variable is          ^This returns a String.
    //    a String* (string
    //    pointer) type
```

You're also redeclaring the variables IP and MAC in your `networkInfo()` function.

I don't know why you have IP and MAC as String pointers, you shouldn't need to. But, if you insist on keeping them that way you just need to do:

```
*IP = WiFi.localIP().toString();
```

Comment: That will crash because `IP` is uninitialized.

Comment: Just tested this and it didnt work. The reason i need them is: There will be a sendInfo() function that sends the variables mapped in networkInfo() ...